# Reassigning to an existing variable after removing vowels from a string?

Tags: python

I have a question regarding this code.  My aim is to remove all vowels from a string:

```
# 'California' is the_word I'm removing vowels from
the_word = "California"  


# a for-loop that will look over and remove any vowels
for vowel in 'aeiou':
    # Assign the expression to an existing variable. Why?
    the_word = the_word.replace(vowel, '')


# print the output
print(the_word)
```

This program works if I reuse 'the_word' variable with a new expression in my for-loop.  However, if I choose to use a new variable (ie, 'new_word') in my for-loop it doesn't work.  For example:

```
the_word = "California"  

for vowel in 'aeiou':
    new_word = the_word.replace(vowel, '')

print(new_word)
```

It may be a silly question, but, why do I have to use the existing variable instead of a new one?

Comment: because you are calling replace on your old variable every time so that means it will always be calling replace on `'California'` rather than on the edited version of the string after each vowel has been replaced. with this, you would be overwriting the value of new_word with a replaced version of each vowel, ie `'Cliforni',Calforna' etc`

Comment: to see what I mean more plainly, put the call to `print` inside of your for loop so it print the value of `new_word` and `the_word` at each iteration

Answer (score 1):

The replace function does not modify the existing string, instead it returns a string contain the requested replacement, as such it needs to either be printed or assigned to a variable.

As an alternative to using `replace`, you will find Python's `maketrans` and `translate` functions are useful for this. In Python 2.7:

```
import string

def disemvowel(s):
    return string.translate(s, string.maketrans("",""), "EAIOUeaiou")

without_vowels = disemvowel("California")
print without_vowels
```

This would display the following:

```
Clfrn
```

Or for Python 3, the following can be used:

```
def disemvowel(s):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans("","", "EAIOUeaiou"))

without_vowels = disemvowel("California")
print(without_vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you are calling `replace` on `the_word` each iteration. `the_word` always equals "California".

Thus, you have the following, after each run:

```
replacing 'a': Cliforni
replacing 'e': California
replacing 'i': Calforna
replacing 'o': Califrnia
replacing 'u': California
```

After 'u' is replaced, you exit your loop and `new_word` equals "California"